# How to figure out where the UV shows on the Mesh?

Tags: mesh

How to figure out where the UV shows on the Mesh?

I know that there is an option or button to find out what part of the UV mapping matches up with the mesh so that fixing problems is easier.

Does anyone know what that option is?

Comment: I remember that the person I saw do this clicked a part of the UV and the mesh itself lit up at the same time. So I don't think this is it?

Comment: That's what that option does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That button right there is probably what you want. Also keep in mind that by default, only faces you have selected in edit mode show up in the UV editor.
[image: Keep UV and selection mode in sync]

Comment: weird, even with the option enabled, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Maybe check what selection mode the uv editor is in. When the option is enabled, you can select vertices, edges, or faces. Same goes for the 3D viewport. Try putting them both into vertex select mode.

Comment: Never mind. I was doing it wrong. I still can't get that to work but I don't need it anymore.
I now realise I can just paint over my model. I was just screencapping the UV maps and using another software to paint in, then bringing them back in as textures and having to keep on going back and forth between the two until it lined up right. - facepalm -